# Утечка памяти phpQuery. Как исправить?

Tags: php, phpquery

Есть функция, которая, используя библиотеку **phpQuery**, парсит данные со страницы на сайте. Данные на странице обновляются регулярно, поэтому функция вызывается в цикле приблизительно каждые 5-10 секунд (в зависимости от скорости получения страницы). После продолжительной работы скрипта, получаю ошибку

**PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1073741824 bytes) in C:\OSPanel\domains\home-page-parcer.ru\phpQuery.php on line 3494**

В **php.ini memory_limit** = 1536M. Скрипт работает на локальном сервере (**OpenServer**).

Провел небольшие исследования расставив в различных частях скрипта **memory_get_usage**. Потребляемая память увеличивается непосредственно после создания объекта **phpQuery** или после одного из циклов **foreach** (1-го либо 2-го сверху) , при этом память не уменьшается после вызова **phpQuery::unloadDocuments()**. Также, память накапливается не после каждого создания объекта phpQuery, а как-то периодически (один раз в несколько итераций, закономерность увеличения не удалось установить). К примеру: было **2097152** после стало **4194304**, спустя несколько итераций значение не изменялось, но после снова увеличилось и стало **6291456**.

Собственно сама функция. Не могу понять в чем проблема и почему **phpQuery::unloadDocuments()**; не работает

```php
function parcer($url){
    $ids=[];
    $indexIds=0;
    $content = get_content($url);

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($content);

    foreach ($doc->find('[id^=name_]:input') as $opt) { // получаем товары которые успели преобразоваться в input
            $opt=pq($opt);
            $numTov = preg_replace('~[^0-9]*~','',$opt->attr('id')); // получаем с ID номер товара
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $numTov;
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->attr('value'); // получаем значение input
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->nextAll('input:first-of-type')->prev('a')->text(); //ищем последнюю ссылку каталога
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->nextAll('nobr')->children('[id^=manf]')->text(); //ищем поставщика
            $indexIds++;
    }

    foreach ($doc->find('td>[id^=name_]:not(:input)') as $opt) { // получаем товары в span, которые без родителя
            $opt=pq($opt);
            $numTov = preg_replace('~[^0-9]*~','',$opt->attr('id'));
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $numTov;
            $ids[$indexIds][]= $opt->text();
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->nextAll('[id^=cats_]:last')->text();
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->nextAll('nobr')->children('[id^=manf]')->text();
            $indexIds++;
    }

    foreach ($doc->find('div>[id^=name_]') as $opt) { // получаем товары в span, которые с родителем
            $opt=pq($opt);
            $numTov = preg_replace('~[^0-9]*~','',$opt->attr('id'));
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $numTov;
            $ids[$indexIds][]= $opt->text();
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->parent()->nextAll('[id^=cats_]:last')->text();
            $ids[$indexIds][] = $opt->parent()->nextAll('nobr')->children('[id^=manf]')->text();
            $indexIds++;
    }

    phpQuery::unloadDocuments(); //очистка документа
    gc_collect_cycles(); // принудительный вызов встроенного сборщика мусора PHP
    return $ids;
    }
```

Comment: Как вариант - загружать данные пакетами, а не всей кучей

Comment: да там данных, кот наплакал. одна страница на 300строчек. просто ее регулярно нужно обновлять, дабы ловить обновления

Answer (score 0):

Да уж... Получу я от "маститых" разрабов минуса, но тем не менее:

1. Присвойте $doc->find("") переменной, а потом уже с ней работайте.
2. В конце каждого цикла используйте unset($opt).
3. Попробуйте "вырезать" весь ненужный мусор со страницы, облегчив итоговый документ.

Comment: 1: не помогло
2: уже пробовал, не помогло(
3: страница сама по себе не тяжелая, и содержит только то инфо которое мне нужно - ничего лишнего(

Comment: @user314085 тогда почитайте еще это (просто сам не пользовался, поэтому дал общие советы) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076074/problem-with-using-phpquery и https://github.com/pein0119/phpquery/issues/192#issuecomment-412307698

Comment: @user314085 а вы можете предоставить страницу, которую парсите? Просто стало интересно самому попробовать)

Comment: DaemonHK, просмотрел предоставленные ссылки, к сожалению проблему не удалось устранить. к сожалению, страницу не могу предоставить, так как к ней закрыт доступ=(